# How to use dependencies from spring-boot-starter-parent?

Tags: maven, transitive-dependency, spring-boot-starter-parent

I have a Spring Boot application using spring-boot-starter-parent 2.5.4:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
</parent>

<groupId>my.group</groupId>
<artifactId>myAtifactId</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>MyName</name>
```

I can see at [Maven spring-boot-starter-parent 2.5.4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.5.4)

that it brings some dependencies I could use. Hence, I want to clean up dependencies added manually to the POM.

I removed some of those manually added dependencies like *assertJ*...and it works but when I remove *Lombok* or *Awaitility*, for instance, the `mvn install` fails. Why does this happen? If I add the dependency again (even without version) `mvn install` succeeds again.
Isn't it possible to remove all dependencies added manually to the POM which are provided transitively by spring-boot-starter-parent?

Using `mvn dependency:tree` I can see that `asserts-core` comes with version 3.19.0 with scope test as described on MVNrepository.
Lombok comes with version 1.18.20 with scope provided as described on MVNrepository. ...but when I remove this form my POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
<!--    <version>${lombok.version}</version>-->
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

...the `mvn install` fails:

```
.
.
.
constituent[42]: file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-plugin-api-3.8.1.jar
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:155)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.check(Assert.java:46)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Modules.enter(Modules.java:247)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.readSourceFile(JavaCompiler.java:837)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ImplicitCompleter.complete(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1530)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:642)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:1326)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.complete(Type.java:1140)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.getTypeArguments(Type.java:1066)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Printer.visitClassType(Printer.java:237)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Printer.visitClassType(Printer.java:52)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:993)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Printer.visit(Printer.java:136)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.formatArgument(AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.java:199)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.formatArguments(AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.java:167)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.BasicDiagnosticFormatter.formatMessage(BasicDiagnosticFormatter.java:111)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.BasicDiagnosticFormatter.formatMessage(BasicDiagnosticFormatter.java:67)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.formatArgument(AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.java:185)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.formatArguments(AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.java:167)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.BasicDiagnosticFormatter.formatMessage(BasicDiagnosticFormatter.java:111)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.BasicDiagnosticFormatter.formatMessage(BasicDiagnosticFormatter.java:67)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.JCDiagnostic.getMessage(JCDiagnostic.java:788)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.ClientCodeWrapper$DiagnosticSourceUnwrapper.getMessage(ClientCodeWrapper.java:799)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:131)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1134)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:187)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Use `mvn dependency:tree` to see the dependencies.

Comment: Weird! Although Awaitility is listed in the dependencies coming from/with spring-boot-starter-parent it is NOT in the dependency tree. How can this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay...lessons learned by [Maven dependencyManagement vs. dependencies Tags](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-dependencymanagement-vs-dependencies-tags) Dependency management is used in order to declare the dependencies in the POM file. This declaration is just an announcement, and it doesn't really add the dependency to the project.
dependencyManagement is just a declaration, and it does not really add a dependency. The declared dependencies in this section must be later used by the dependencies tag. It is just the dependencies tag that causes real dependency to happen.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove Lombok dependency in your application then how the application will compile without knowing what the @Data(Class level annotation)is it so it fails ,if you want to run without lombok dependency then remove those annotations in your application which are from lombok and have some setter and getter methods then it will work

Comment: spring-boot-starter-parent brings Lombok automatically. So why should I add it manually again? Same with assertJ. I could remove the manually added dependency. Hence, I think @Data should be well known in the application.

Comment: spring boot starter parent doesn't include lombok dependency, manually when you are typing @Data and while pressing enter the ide automatically installs the lombok dependency